# json: when clicking on a category link I want to display only posts in that category

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to get posts lists assigned to each category and display the title with slug as link, I do not want to hardcode the category name but instead want to grab each posts assigned to each category. I hope this make sense.

my question is, how do I compare if the post is part of the category slug "all-qualified-retirement-plans"?

What I want to do is... When I click on link "#all-qualified-retirement-plans", I  only want those posts to show with the category slug "all-qualified-retirement-plans"

```
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">

    <li data-id="4" data-parent="1" class="ui-first-child">
<a href="#all-qualified-retirement-plans" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">All Qualified Retirement Plans</a></li>

  <li data-id="7" data-parent="0" class="ui-first-child">
<a href="#fica-ss-medicare-taxes" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">FICA - SS &amp; MEDICARE TAXES</a></li>

  <li data-id="2" data-parent="0">
<a href="#healthcare-plans" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r"/> Healthcare Plans </a></li>

      <li data-id="3" data-parent="0">
<a href="#other-benefits" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">Other Benefits</a></li>

        </ul>


function allQualifiedRetirementPlans(data) {
  "use strict";

  var output = '<ul  data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search..." >';

  $.each(data.posts, function(key, val) {
    output += '<li>';
    output += '<a href="#' + val.slug + '">';  // post slug
    output += '<h3>' + val.title + "</h3>";  // post title
    output += '</a>';
    output += '</li>';
  }); //go through each post


  output += "</ul>";
  $('#all-qualified-retirement-plans-postlist').html(output);
```

//json

```
var data = {
      "status": "ok",
        "count": 24,
        "count_total": 24,
        "pages": 1,
        "posts": [
            {
                "id": 131,
                "type": "benefits",
                "slug": "highly-compensated-employee-hce",
                "url": "http://mywebsite.com/benefits/highly-compensated-employee-hce/",
                "status": "publish",
                "title": "Highly Compensated Employee (“HCE”)",
                "title_plain": "Highly Compensated Employee (“HCE”)",
                "content": "<p>Qualified Retirement Plans must not favor Highly Compensated Employees (HCEs). HCEs are used in testing for discrimination, such as testing employee and employer contributions under a 401(k) plan. An HCE is one who either: a) owns more than 5% of the organization, either directly or indirectly, no matter what that person’s pay is, or b) any employee whose pay from the organization, for the previous year, exceeds the amount shown below.</p>\n",
                "excerpt": "<p>Qualified Retirement Plans must not favor Highly Compensated Employees (HCEs). HCEs are used in testing for discrimination, such as testing employee and employer contributions under a 401(k) plan. An HCE is one who either: a) owns more than 5% of the organization, either directly or indirectly, no matter what that person’s pay is, or b) &hellip; <a href=\"http://mywebsite/benefits/highly-compensated-employee-hce/\" class=\"more-link\">Continue reading<span class=\"screen-reader-text\"> &#8220;Highly Compensated Employee (“HCE”)&#8221;</span></a></p>\n",
                "date": "2016-04-01 18:06:34",
                "modified": "2016-04-01 18:06:54",
                "categories": [
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "slug": "all-qualified-retirement-plans",
                        "title": "All Qualified Retirement Plans",
                        "description": "",
                        "parent": 1,
                        "post_count": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "slug": "retirement-plans",
                        "title": "Retirement Plans",
                        "description": "",
                        "parent": 0,
                        "post_count": 13
                    }
                ],
                "tags": [],
                "author": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "slug": "keith",
                    "name": "keith",
                    "first_name": "",
                    "last_name": "",
                    "nickname": "keith",
                    "url": "",
                    "description": ""
                },
                "comments": [],
                "attachments": [],
                "comment_count": 0,
                "comment_status": "closed",
                "custom_fields": {
                    "extra_content_extra_content_title": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "extra_content_extra_content_medicare": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "extra_content_extra_content_percent_moved": [
                        " "
                    ],
                    "extra_content_extra_content_percent_value": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "extra_content_extra_content_first_value": [
                        "2016: 120,000"
                    ],
                    "extra_content_extra_content_second_value": [
                        "2015: 120,000"
                    ],
                    "extra_content_extra_content_third_value": [
                        "2014: 115,000"
                    ],
                    "extra_content_extra_content_fourth_value": [
                        "2013: 115,000"
                    ],
                    "extra_content_extra_content_firth_value": [
                        "2012: 115,000"
                    ],
                    "extra_content_extra_content_sixth_value": [
                        "2011: 110,000"
                    ],
                    "extra_content_extra_content_seventh_value": [
                        "2010: 110,000"
                    ],
                    "extra_content_extra_content_eight_value": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "extra_content_extra_content_nine_value": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "extra_content_extra_content_ten_value": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "social_security_social_security_title": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "social_security_social_security_field_one": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "social_security_social_security_field_two": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "social_security_social_security_field_three": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "social_security_social_security_field_four": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "social_security_social_security_field_five": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "social_security_social_security_field_six": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "social_security_social_security_field_seven": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "social_security_social_security_field_eight": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "social_security_social_security_field_nine": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "social_security_social_security_field_ten": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "extra_content_three_title": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "extra_content_three_field_one": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "extra_content_three_field_two": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "extra_content_three_field_three": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "extra_content_three_field_four": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "extra_content_three_field_five": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "extra_content_three_field_six": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "extra_content_three_field_seven": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "extra_content_three_field_eight": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "extra_content_three_field_nine": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "extra_content_three_field_ten": [
                        ""
                    ]
                }
            }
};

allQualifiedRetirementPlans (data)
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: the code does not work

Comment: Don't know what you want help with, but consider using a templating engine for stuff like this so you don't have to do all that string concatenation stuff, it's a nightmare to maintain.  Example: http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: @smerny can you explain

Comment: do  you have a code example?

Comment: I'm uncertain of what isn't working. Fixing a couple of (what I assume are copy+paste issues) syntax errors. I get the following fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/5yyg3req/

Comment: my question is, how do I compare if the post is part of the category slug "all-qualified-retirement-plans"?

Comment: "the code does not work" is not a question. You seem to have a misunderstanding about Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though you are missing the close `]` from the `"posts"` field in the data object.

**Update**

I also included the logic to loop over the categories to see if the slug exists in the object array.

Also, just to show you don't need jQuery for simple loops, I removed the $.each() method

See this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/5yyg3req/2/

Comment: my question is, how do I compare if the post is part of the category slug "all-qualified-retirement-plans"?

Comment: can you revise your answer?

Comment: @velvetInk I have updated the fiddler to include all of the logic